# Python: integer is not being converted to string while using format in a text

Tags: python

I have a string where two placeholders are present to accommodate dynamic values. One of them accepts integer and the other one accepts string.

```
s_1 = int(sys.argv[1])
s_2 = str(sys.argv[2])
sql = "SELECT * FROM script.fn_function({0},{1});".format(s_1,str(s_2))
```

When I am passing values for `s_1` and `s_2` as 100, 200 then ideally my `sql` string should read like below:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM script.fn_function(100,'200')'
```

But when I run the above, I am getting as

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM script.fn_function(100,200);'
```

So in other words, `.format(s_1,str(s_2))` is not exactly working.

What I am missing here? Never faced such issue.

Comment: When you print a string, quotes aren't printed. Use `'{1}'`.

Comment: You should probably be using the parameterised queries API of your SQL adapter, something like `db.query('... fn_function(%s, %s)', (s_1, s_2))`…

Answer (score 0):

When you inject the string with `.format` it won't add `''` for you.
Best would be to write

```py
sql = "SELECT * FROM script.fn_function({0},'{1}');".format(s_1, s_2)
```

Edit: I removed the str form the format since as pointed out it is redundant.

Also as other people suggested use parametrized queries for more security

Comment: using `str` when passing arguments to `.format` is redundant. It is already doing that. Also, this code is sql-injection-able. If you are already showing OP a better way, use a parametrized query.

Comment: Best to not enable SQL injection attacks

Comment: I am only answering the question. SQL injections are something else. he might have had this in other places so what is wrong with showing the answer to the expected output he wanted ?